# Why does gcloud crash when multiple scopes are passed?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm adding scopes to an access token via this gcloud command: `gcloud auth application-default login --scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'`. It works fine when I'm only adding 1 scope but whenever I try adding another like so `gcloud auth application-default login --scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'`, I am brought to the consent screen where I see the scopes provided. Upon accepting, I get this in my terminal:

```sh
ERROR: gcloud crashed (Warning): Scope has changed from "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/accounts.reauth" to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/accounts.reauth https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
```

Any idea why this is happening? Am I not passing the scopes correctly?

NB. The scopes shown are already added in the console on GCP.

Comment: I cannot answer for the crash, but you should revoke the credentials before requesting new ones with different scopes **gcloud auth application-default revoke**. Also, **scopes** is a comma-separated list. It appears you are using spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the spaces anywhere in your scope list, and use commas instead to separate each scope (in addition to enclosing the whole list in quotes), like so:

```
gcloud auth application-default login --scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
```

I received the same error at first using your command, but after looking at this [issue report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185162453), it's caused by gcloud parsing the arguments incorrectly when spaces are present. Using the command above resolved it on my test.